# Page Not Appearing In Magento

Tags: magento, content-management-system, invisible

IM having a weird instance where a page created via the CMS backend is not showing on the site. This is only happening on one of the pages out of 40 that i have newly created. I have tried deleting the page and remaking it but this produces the same error. I have also tried changing the status to Disabled and back to Enabled but that didn't work either.

I simply just get a white page with no errors in the console or otherwise. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried creating this page with no content etc?  Have you cleared caches?

Comment: Which stores are selected in this cms page?

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a little light on the details a programmer needs to help you, so here's how I'd debug this

Magento looks for a CMS page in the following method.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Resource/Page.php
public function checkIdentifier($identifier, $storeId)
{
    $stores = array(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID, $storeId);
    $select = $this->_getLoadByIdentifierSelect($identifier, $stores, 1);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns('cp.page_id')
        ->order('cps.store_id DESC')
        ->limit(1);

    return $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchOne($select);
}
```

This code generates a SQL query that compares the identifier in the URL with what it can find in the `cms_page` table.  For someone reason this query is returning zero rows in your Magento instance.  Add some temporary debugging code to output the SQL query

```
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns('cp.page_id')
        ->order('cps.store_id DESC')
        ->limit(1);

    echo '<pre>';
    echo $select->__toString();
    echo '</pre>';
    exit(__METHOD__ . '::' . __LINE__);
    return $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchOne($select);
```

and determine why your query is returning no rows.

Comment: Well this is the message i got: SELECT `cms_page`.* FROM `cms_page`
 INNER JOIN `cms_page_store` ON cms_page.page_id = cms_page_store.page_id WHERE (`cms_page`.`page_id`='68') AND (is_active = 1) AND (cms_page_store.store_id IN (0, 1)) ORDER BY `cms_page_store`.`store_id` DESC LIMIT 1
Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page::_getLoadSelect::214

Comment: I looked in the DB and the paeg i am trying to access is indeed page id = 68. Still confused. Gremlins man..

Comment: @user2584696 Did you run the SQL against your database and get back a row?

Comment: Yes, and its retrieving the correct page (row) and everything.. real confused now.

Comment: @user2584696 Just re-read your question — a simple white page (with a blank HTML source?) indicated a PHP or Magento error of some kind.  Put your site in developer mode, with display_errors set to 1 (or check both your Magento exception and PHP error log) and the error should become evident.